# How to check if dynamically generated radio button are clicked in the form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating a form with multiple choice questions  using php , Now I want to check if each and every question has been answered or not by checking if radio buttons for each question are clicked.

```php
<div class="opt">
    <div class="row1">                                                 
      <label class="label">{{ $question->question }}</label>
    </div>
<div class="ans">                                                            
  $answer=$answers[$question->id]
  @foreach ($answer as $answer)
     <label class="btn btn-default no-margin-rule" >
        <input type="radio" name="{{$count+1}}" value="{{$answer->id}}" id="ans{{$answer->answer}}" />
        <span class="option{{$answer->answer+1}}"></span>
      </label>
    @endforeach
  </div>
 </div>
```

```js
$("#sub").click(function() {
  var check = true;
  $("input:radio").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');
    if ($("input:radio[name=" + name + "]:checked").length) {
      check = true;
    } else {
      check = false;
    }
  });

  if (check) {
    $("#form1").submit();
  } else {
    swal("Oops!", "Please select at least one answer in each question.", "error")
  }
});
```

Comment: I assume your current JS doesn't work, if so what does it do/not do? Please also add a sample of your HTML to the question so we can recreate the issue.

Comment: In the `if else`, remove the `check = true;` it overwrites the `check = false;` when an unchecked radio is followed by a checked radio.

Comment: Is there a loop for questions?

Comment: Make sure all anwers for any given question have the same `name` value.

Comment: @CuongLeNgoc yes there is a loop for a question too ...... I mean there can be 10-15  question in a form each question has MCQs which are represented by a radio button

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there are multiple questions, as you state in the comments under the question, then all you need to check the total number of `.ans` elements matches the number of `.ans` elements which contain a checked radio, like this:

```
$("#sub").click(function() {
  var $answers = $('.ans');
  var valid = $answers.length == $answers.filter(':has(:radio:checked)').length;

  if (valid ) {
    $("#form1").submit();
  } else {
    swal("Oops!", "Please select at least one answer in each question.", "error")
  }
});
```

As a side note I would suggest you do perform this check under the `submit` event of the `form` element, instead of the click of a button, for accessibility reasons.

Comment: Why not do `var valid = [...$('.ans')].every($answer => $answer(':has(:radio:checked)'))`? That feels alot more readable and concise.

Comment: Sure, that's an alternative. The spread syntax would give you issues in IE, though.

Comment: Use `Array.prototype.every.call($('.ans'), function($answer) { return $answer(':has(:radio:checked)'); } )` then.

Answer (score 0):

This is - as always - very easy to achieve using standard vanilla Javascript. No jQuery necessary.

```js
document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  const check =  [...document.forms[0].querySelectorAll('fieldset')].every(fieldset => !!fieldset.querySelector('input:checked'));
  console.log(`${check ? 'A' : 'Not a'}ll questions have been answered!`);
  // for demo purposes, prevent the submit regardless
  event.preventDefault();
  // in your code, you'd do the check
  // if (!check) event.preventDefault();
})
```

```css
form { display: flex; }
```

```html
<form id="questions">
    <fieldset>
      <legend>What is 1+1?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="addition" id="addition1" value="3" />
      <label for="addition1">3</label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="addition" id="addition2" value="1" />
      <label for="addition2">1</label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="addition" id="addition3" value="2" />
      <label for="addition3">2</label>
      <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <legend>What is 1*1?</legend>
      <input type="radio" name="multiplication" id="multiplication1" value="3" />
      <label for="multiplication1">3</label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="multiplication" id="multiplication2" value="1" />
      <label for="multiplication2">1</label>
      <br />
      <input type="radio" name="multiplication" id="multiplication3" value="2" />
      <label for="multiplication3">2</label>
      <br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <legend>What is 1-1?</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="subtraction" id="subtraction1" value="-1" />
        <label for="subtraction1">-1</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="subtraction" id="subtraction2" value="0" />
        <label for="subtraction2">0</label>
        <br />
        <input type="radio" name="subtraction" id="subtraction3" value="1" />
        <label for="subtraction3">1</label>
        <br />
      </fieldset>
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```